# Why is $\{\omega \in \Omega\mid \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\}$ measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_n)_n$ and $X$ be real valued random variables ($(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}) $). Why is the set $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\}$ measurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Show that it equals the set

$$\bigcap_{k\in \Bbb N}\bigcup_{N\in \Bbb N}\bigcap_{n\geq N}\big\{|X_n-X|<\frac{1}{k}\big\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your set is
$$\{\omega \in \Omega\mid \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^+_0: \exists n_0: \forall n \ge n_0: |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| < \epsilon\}$$
which equals
$$\bigcap_{\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}_0^+}\bigcup_{n_0=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n =n_0}^\infty \{\omega \in \Omega\mid |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| < \epsilon\}$$

which is clearly measurable.